# Kann »aufgrund« eine mit Komma abtrennbare Apposition einleiten?

Tags: punctuation, comma, apposition

In diesem [Thread](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/hinter-aufgrund-ein-komma) wird die Kommaregelung folgenden Satzes diskutiert:

> Ich bitte Sie, mein Fehlen am XXXX, aufgrund starker Kopfschmerzen, zu entschuldigen.

Der Großteil behauptet, dass vor *aufgrund* und vor *zu* keine Kommata stehen, allerdings halte ich das für eine legitime Apposition. Liege ich hier falsch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eine Apposition ist es sicherlich nicht (zu was denn?); man kann aber trotzdem Kommata setzen, oder auch Gedankenstriche, wenn man die Erklärung als Einschub verstanden wissen will. Üblicher wäre es aber ohne.

Man vermeidet das Problem und das wenig elegante *aufgrund* völlig, wenn man zwei Sätze daraus macht:

> Ich bitte Sie, mein Fehlen am Mittwoch zu entschuldigen. Ich hatte starke Kopfschmerzen.

Comment: Dankeschön. Könnte man dann nicht im zweiten Satz des Threads, auf den du mir vorhin geantwortet hast, nicht auch Kommata setzen, da es sich um einen Einschub handelt?

Comment: @Godofgramma: Meiner Meinung nach ist _der den Schaden betreffenden Stelle_ in jenem Satz (Link: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24004) nötig, der Satz ist sonst nicht sinnvoll. Für einen Einschub ist aber wesentlich, daß man ihn weglassen kann. Selbst wenn man annimmt, daß es sich aus dem Zusammenhang ergibt, bräuchte ich für mein Sprachgefühl eine Markierung wie _und zwar_ oder _nämlich_.

Comment: Vielen herzlichen Dank!